# How to disable automatic secret rotation of AWS Secrets Manager using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a secret stored in AWS Secrets Manager deployed using a Terraform module which enables secret rotation. I don't have access to the source code of that module so I can't modify it. I want to disable the secret rotation using Terraform. Which resource should I use ? The `aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation` requires all 3 arguments as shown below and doesn't have any parameter to disable the rotation. The `automatically_after_days` attribute accepts value between 1 to 365, so, passing 0 is not an option either.

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation" "example" {
  secret_id           = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.id
  rotation_lambda_arn = aws_lambda_function.example.arn

  rotation_rules {
    automatically_after_days = 30
  }
}
```

Comment: Why use that module if it's doing something you don't want and you have no way to influence what it's doing?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't bypass it as it's a by-product of a bigger module that I am using.

Comment: Can you fork the module? It's presumably already setting the rotation via the `aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation` resource so adding another `aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation` resource would cause a conflict anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can just skip "aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation" resource completely and terraform will disable rotation automatically.

Comment: If you want to keep the resource, you can also use the rotation_enabled property
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/secretsmanager_secret_rotation#rotation_enabled

Comment: I believe rotation_enabled is an export attribute and output value that you can't set, although I don't quite understand how you can keep the resource and has rotation_enable output as false

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that terraform provider calls the following API from AWS SDK [rotate-secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/rotate-secret.html). This API doesn't provide any option to disable automatic rotation and keep the configuration. That would be useful if you'd like to run rotation manually, but not automatically by a schedule job.

You can see that this is a AWS limitation because if you call [cancel-rotate-secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/cancel-rotate-secret.html) it disables the rotation procedure at all, and do not update any flag in the main secret resource. That means, the way it's implemented on AWS, doesn't allow to implement this in terraform in a way there's a one-to-one relationship between AWS components and AWS resources I suppose.